# Cannot save C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\Блокнот\main_update_01.py. Unable to create a backup file (main_update_01.py~). The file left unchanged

Tags: python, pycharm

Всем привет. Писал я значит код в pycharm и вдруг при попытке запустить и сохранить файл, мне прилетает вот такая ласточка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не нашёл объяснение в интернете, и вообще впервые с этим сталкиваюсь. Что мне делать?

Также, хочу отметить, что в моей версии PyCharm нет 'Back up files before saving' в настройках[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте выключить 'Back up files before saving' в Settings > Appearance and Behavior > System Settings.

Comment: В  System Settings нет такой опции

Comment: Точно? ) [А тут есть](https://ibb.co/j39jcry)

Comment: Я добавил изображение к вопросу

Comment: Ясно, у Вас Community Edition похоже. Уберите галочку с пункта 'safe write'

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Но у меня ещё один вопрос: вы не знаете как отключить хост процесс Windows(Rundll32)?

Comment: Если помогло, то отметьте ответ как принятый ). а по поводу Rundll32 [почитайте тут](https://hetmanrecovery.com/ru/recovery_news/the-process-rundll32-exe-and-why-it-is-running-on-my-pc.htm?__c=1)